# Can the borrow checker know when an Arc is "released"? Can a 'static lifetime granted temporarily?

Tags: multithreading, rust, borrow-checker

I'm trying to speed up a computationally-heavy Rust function by making it concurrent using only the built-in thread support.  In particular, I want to alternate between quick single-threaded phases (where the main thread has mutable access to a big structure) and concurrent phases (where many worker threads run with read-only access to the structure).  I don't want to make extra copies of the structure or force it to be `'static`.  Where I'm having trouble is convincing the borrow checker that the worker threads have finished.

Ignoring the borrow checker, an `Arc` reference seems like does all that is needed.  The reference count in the `Arc` increases with the `.clone()` for each worker, then decreases as the workers conclude and I join all the worker threads.  If (and only if) the `Arc` reference count is 1, it should be safe for the main thread to resume.  The borrow checker, however, doesn't seem to know about `Arc` reference counts, and insists that my structure needs to be `'static`.

Here's some sample code which works fine if I don't use threads, but won't compile if I switch the comments to enable the multi-threaded case.

```
struct BigStruct { 
    data: Vec<usize>
    // Lots more
}
pub fn main() {
    let ref_bigstruct = &mut BigStruct { data: Vec::new() };
    for i in 0..3 {
        ref_bigstruct.data.push(i);    // Phase where main thread has write access
        run_threads(ref_bigstruct);    // Phase where worker threads have read-only access
    }
}

fn run_threads(ref_bigstruct: &BigStruct) {
    let arc_bigstruct = Arc::new(ref_bigstruct);
    {
        let arc_clone_for_worker = arc_bigstruct.clone();

        // SINGLE-THREADED WORKS:
        worker_thread(arc_clone_for_worker);

        // MULTI-THREADED DOES NOT COMPILE:
        // let handle = thread::spawn(move || { worker_thread(arc_clone_for_worker); } );
        // handle.join();
    }
    assert!(Arc::strong_count(&arc_bigstruct) == 1);
    println!("??? How can I tell the borrow checker that all borrows of ref_bigstruct are done?")
}

fn worker_thread(my_struct: Arc<&BigStruct>) {
    println!("   worker says len()={}", my_struct.data.len()); 
}
```

I'm still learning about Rust lifetimes, but what I think (fear?) what I need is an operation that will take an ordinary (not `'static`) reference to my structure and give me an `Arc` that I can clone into immutable references with a `'static` lifetime for use by the workers.  Once all the the worker `Arc` references are dropped, the borrow checker needs to allow my thread-spawning function to return.  For safety, I assume this would panic if the the reference count is >1.  While this seems like it would generally confirm with Rust's safety requirements, I don't see how to do it.

Comment: Check out `Arc::try_unwrap()` and `Arc::get_mut()`. Here's an idea but not sure if this is what you want: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d2dabc2f60e1c811a76c02d9b9e0a378.

Answer (score 3):

The underlying problem is not the borrowing checker not following `Arc` and the solution is not to use `Arc`. The problem is the borrow checker being unable to understand that the reason a thread must be `'static` is because it may outlive the spawning thread, and thus if I immediately `.join()` it it is fine.

And the solution is to use scoped threads, that is, threads that allow you to use non-`'static` data because they *always* immediately `.join()`, and thus the spawned thread cannot outlive the spawning thread. Problem is, there are no worker threads on the standard library. Well, [there are](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/thread/fn.scope.html), however they're unstable.

So if you insist on not using crates, for some reason, you have no choice but to use `unsafe` code (don't, really). But if you can use external crates, then you can use the well-known [`crossbeam`](https://docs.rs/crossbeam) crate with its [`crossbeam::scope`](https://docs.rs/crossbeam/latest/crossbeam/fn.scope.html) function, at least til std's scoped threads are stabilized.

Comment: Following up, I tried crossbeam's scoped threads, and they work nicely.  While I don't know if crossbeam has the same problematic corner cases as (apparently) the prior Rust standard version of scoped threads, for my purposes it's more than adequate.

Comment: @rustingaway They don't. They were designed based on this prior experience. And the corner cases were soundness holes, not something that will cause you to feel it's inadequate.

Comment: Thanks again for the help!  While my code is working, I'm still puzzling over part of my original question -- is there a safety reason why there isn't a way to use Arc() to allow safe Rust code to temporarily promote an ordinary lifetime to 'static (with a block/panic if there are dangling references)?

Comment: @rustingaway First, like I said, this is unrelated to `Arc`: if the thread will live longer than the reference you might have a use after free. Second, Rust's borrowck doesn't follow user code, and never will.

Answer (score 1):

In Rust Arc< T>, T is per definition immutable. Which means in order to use Arc, to make threads access data that is going to change, you also need it to wrap in some type that is interiorly mutable.
Rust provides a type that is especially suited for a single write or multiple read accesses in parallel, called [RwLock](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.RwLock.html).

So for your simple example, this would propably look something like this

```
use std::{sync::{Arc, RwLock}, thread};

struct BigStruct { 
    data: Vec<usize>
    // Lots more
}
pub fn main() {
    let arc_bigstruct = Arc::new(RwLock::new(BigStruct { data: Vec::new() }));
    for i in 0..3 {
        arc_bigstruct.write().unwrap().data.push(i);    // Phase where main thread has write access
        
        run_threads(&arc_bigstruct);    // Phase where worker threads have read-only access
    }
}

fn run_threads(ref_bigstruct: &Arc<RwLock<BigStruct>>) {
    {
        let arc_clone_for_worker = ref_bigstruct.clone();

        //MULTI-THREADED 
        let handle = thread::spawn(move || { worker_thread(&arc_clone_for_worker); } );
         handle.join().unwrap();
    }
    assert!(Arc::strong_count(&ref_bigstruct) == 1);
}

fn worker_thread(my_struct: &Arc<RwLock<BigStruct>>) {
    println!("   worker says len()={}", my_struct.read().unwrap().data.len()); 
}
```

Which outputs

> worker says len()=1
>
> worker says len()=2
>
> worker says len()=3

As for your question, the borrow checker does not know when an Arc is released, as far as I know. The references are counted at runtime.

Comment: I would like to add, without `handle.join().unwrap();`, there would be no guarantee, that your thread actually reads the data before `arc_bigstruct.write().unwrap().data.push(i);` changes it. If your worker threads need further synchronization, I'd recommend a channel, by which threads can communicate with each other, including blocking when trying to receive data that has not yet been sent. Rust provides a [channel in the std library](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/) that you can use, but I personally recommend [flume](https://crates.io/crates/flume)

Comment: `RwLock` (or `Mutex`) can solve the problem, but its source is not explained here.